# SQL calculation color "If Sum= ># then /Color/"

Tags: sql, colors, format

Not a DBA,
Just trying to find the right switch for a query calculation I have pulling some stats. I was it to display RED and BOLD if the sum is ># specified

IIF([Sum].[Day_totalcalls] > 5, /*Red*/)

Comment: what is your DB engine? Add the relevant tag.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server?

Comment: I'm thinking you're using SQL Server?  `IIF` doesn't work quite that way. It's `IIF (<boolean>, <true result>,<false result>)`. So for your example, `IIF ([Sum].[Day_totalcalls]> 5,'/RED/',<you need a false value>)`.  BTW, do you really have a table named `Sum`?

Comment: I am using SQL 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

IIF is a new feature in SQL SERVER 2012. You must use a CASE statement.

Provided that you want to have a calculated column which will only have the value 'RED' if your sum is greater than 5 and an empty string in any other case the following should work:

```
CASE 
    WHEN [Sum].[Day_totalcalls] > 5 
    THEN 'RED' 
    ELSE '' 
END
```

Comment: When I put in CASE  WHEN [Sum].[Day_totalcalls] > 5  THEN 'RED'  ELSE '' END  I keep getting 

"Problem with subscription: Subscription failed! Check your query"

Comment: what is your full query?